# Get maximum of comma-separated values in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a cell I have comma-separated numbers. I would like to have the max value of these numbers.

eg: A1 = "2,5,1,4"

what should be the formula in B1 to return the value 5?

Comment: How many numbers do you have?

Comment: @user3819867: Who cares? That's what makes this interesting!

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: It will be larger and larger nested functions.

Comment: @user3819867: Or will it... Have a look at some of the other answers.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: using VBE. When they ask for a function you don't respond with a custom function due to the limitations of VBA. barry houdini made a great counterexample.

Comment: @user3819867: Not clear what your point is, but are you saying that if the OP asks for an Excel formula, then formulas containing user-defined functions are inadmissible? I don't see how that can be true (unless the OP specifies this special requirement explicitly). A formula involving a UDF is still a formula.

Comment: I didn't rule this out, just asked OP whether he was having low numerosity sets that would be simply solved by Excel's built-in functions or 6,000 element sets that could not be solved by these solutions. Your "Who cares?" loses touch with the OPs issue. He didn't tag the question *excel-vba*, therefore I assume he's not familiar with/intending to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `A1` contains a list of positive integers between `1` and `999`, separated by commas but with no spaces, you can use this formula to find the highest number present

`=MATCH(1000,INDEX(FIND(","&ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))&",",","&A1&","),0))`

That searches for all numbers between 1 and 999 and `MATCH` finds the "position" of the last (MAX) of those which, because we start at 1, is the same as the number itself

This works for **any** amount of numbers within A1, in any order, as long as they are in the specified format

Comment: I assume you mean the part that concatenates the commas. Guilty as charged!

Comment: Wow. `ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))`. Wow. Wow.

Comment: this is an interesting solution.  how would you change this to get the Min value?

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBA function here:

```
Public Function MAXSPLIT(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Delimiter As String) As Double
    Dim TextArray() As String
    TextArray = Split(Text, Delimiter)
    Dim ValueArray() As Double
    ReDim Preserve ValueArray(UBound(TextArray))
    For I = LBound(TextArray) To UBound(TextArray)
        ValueArray(I) = CDbl(TextArray(I))
    Next
    ' You can use any other function here: Average, Min etc.
    MAXSPLIT = WorksheetFunction.Max(ValueArray)
End Function
```

Works with any number of values and any delimiter. Usage (you specify string of values and delimiter):

```
=MAXSPLIT("2,5,6,7,8.1,3.254",",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might parse you data with comma as the delimiter and then take the max of the resulting pairs of cells, or you might apply a formula like:

```
=MAX(1*LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),1*MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: Could you please suggest a change such that the formula could be scaled for 3 or 4 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no built-in `SPLIT` function in Excel to split a string using a given delimiter, but you can write a quick wrapper for VBA's `Split` function:

```
Public Function SplitXL(ByVal s As String, Optional delim As String = " ") As String()
    SplitXL = Split(s, delim)
End Function
```

This is then usable in Excel formulas. Note that it returns an array of strings; to be maxable, these strings first need to be parsed as numbers using the `VALUE` function. This gives an array of numbers on which `MAX` can operate.

You can get your desired result using this array formula

```
=MAX(VALUE(SplitXL(A1,",")))
```

which, as any other array formula, must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

=MAX(SPLIT(A1, ","))

Max value from a csv string:

[image: Max value from a csv string]