# max from single cell, and then mean

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
      A
1    5,6
2    8,0
```

What I want:

- max of each cell (from ex: `A1`=>`6`, `A2`=>`8`)
- mean/average of all max (from ex: `(6+8)/2 = 7`)
- all these with only formulas (and without cell splitting), possible? (Say `A3`=*your nice formula*, so that `A3` shows `7`)

Adding vba:

```
Sub maxAndMean()
    TotalNonZeroC = 0
    sumOfMax = 0
    For Each c In Selection
        If IsEmpty(c.Value) = False Then
            TotalC = TotalC + 1
            maxVal = "=Max(Left(c.Value, 1), Right(c.Value, 1))"
            'Not working formula^
            If maxVal != 0 Then
                sumOfMax = sumOfMax + maxVal
                TotalNonZeroC = TotalNonZeroC + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    avg = sumOfMax / TotalNonZeroC
    'How to write avg to next cell(row) in the selected column?
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it's near impossible to do. Take lokk at this: [Get maximum of comma-separated values in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005956/get-maximum-of-comma-separated-values-in-a-cell)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, using vba?

Comment: Using VBA it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `MAX` with a formula, if you have Excel 2013+

```
=MAX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))
```

For the `AVERAGE`, just average the column of MAX's.  And note that AVERAGE will ignore blank cells

**EDIT**

Another variation, where the `AVERAGE` formula only needs to refer to the original data:

**MAX for each cell**

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(. < preceding::*) and not(. < following::*)]")
```

**AVERAGE for the Range**

```
=AVERAGE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2:A3,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(. < preceding::*) and not(. < following::*)]"))
```

The `AVERAGE` formula is an array formula.  In some versions of Excel, to enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

If you have 2007-2010, you can use, for Max:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),1)
```

where

```
seq_99 refers to:  =IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Comment: **MAX for each cell** is working, **AVERAGE for the Range** is not working. Can you please check. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What version of Excel?

Comment: The AVERAGE formula is an array formula.  You may need to confirm it by holding down ctrl+shift while hitting enter.

Comment: Excel 2019. It shows `#VALUE!`. For checking, I tried "show calculation steps", where I found in the 1st step when `A2:A3` evaluates, it shows "next evaluation will result in error", and replaces `A2:A3` with `#VALUE!`.

Comment: please add `ctrl+shift` part to the answer.

Comment: @Mr.EU I will, but I'm surprised that you need it in 2019.  I have O365 and don't. Possibly you don't have the dynamic arrays yet.

Answer (score 0):

With VBA it's pretty simple:

```
Sub ExtractAverage()
    a1max = MaxFromArray(Split(Cells(1, 1), ","))
    a2max = MaxFromArray(Split(Cells(2, 1), ","))
    Cells(3, 1).Value = (a1max + a2max) / 2
End Sub
' note that you can easily find more optimal ways to find maximum of an array,
' This isn't the most optimal solution.
Function MaxFromArray(arr As Variant) As Long
    element = arr(LBound(arr))
    For Each e In arr
        If e > element Then
            element = e
        End If
    Next
    MaxFromArray = element
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for your example but will not scale like a good VBA solution.

A3=your nice formula:

```
=AVERAGE(MAX(LEFT(A1;1);RIGHT(A1;1));MAX(LEFT(A2;1);RIGHT(A2;1)))
```